# Is it possible to use Amazon Web Application Firewall with application that not hosted on AWS instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, web-application-firewall, amazon-cloudfront

I'm new with AWS WAF and get stuck with setting up it for application that hosts on some dedicated server. I didn't find any information how to set up it without migration to aws servers, but I found that WAF integrated with CloudFront. But anyway I found only few information that explain how to integrate this CDN with my web application. So, the main question is:
Is it possible to use AWS WAF with application that hosted on some dedicated server? And if it possible - can you provide some guides and/or docs for setting up?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use WAF with a server outside AWS.

WAF works with CloudFront, and CloudFront does not require the origin server to be in the AWS ecosystem.

> When you create a distribution, you specify where CloudFront sends requests for the files. CloudFront supports using several AWS resources as origins. For example, you can specify an Amazon S3 bucket or a MediaStore container, a MediaPackage channel, or a custom origin, such as an Amazon EC2 instance **or your own HTTP web server.** *(emphasis added)*
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html

Configuring CloudFront to work with your external server is no different than configuring it to work with a server in EC2.  Your DNS entry (e.g. `www.example.com`) changes to point to CloudFront, and CloudFront connects to your server using a new name that you create (e.g. `origin.example.com`).   CloudFront proxies requests through to your server, unless the edge location handling the a given request happens to have access to a copy of the same resource that it cached while handling a previous request for the same page -- that's how CloudFront gets your content, by caching it as it handles requests that are passing through. (You don't pre-load any content into CloudFront.)  If CloudFront has a cached copy, your server sees nothing, and CloudFront returns the object to the browser from its cache.  But CloudFront isn't strictly a CDN, even though they market it that way.  It is a global network of reverse proxies and high-reliability/low-latency transport.

You'll want to take steps to ensure that the web server rejected requests that didn't come through CloudFront.  See [Using Custom Headers to Restrict Access to Your Content on a Custom Origin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/forward-custom-headers.html#forward-custom-headers-restrict-access) as well as the [list of CloudFront IP Addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html) which you could use on your web server's firewall.

Once you have your site working through CloudFront, all you do is activate WAF on the distribution.  CloudFront is very tightly integrated with WAF so that is a very simple change, once you have your WAF rules set up.